# Why are these Swagger endpoints behind a reverse-proxy not found?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a small number of ASP.NET Core services, all running in Docker (via Docker Compose). All services are currently using a prefixed route (their own service name). And they're all setup in Docker Compose to use their own service name as their hostname (connectivity between service containers is OK).

The `/api-docs` endpoint is provided by [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore); we setup the prefixed route here, too.

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    options.RouteTemplate = "scheduler/api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.RoutePrefix = "scheduler/api-docs";
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/scheduler/api-docs/v1/swagger.json", "Scheduler API v1");
});
```

I am trying to configure an Nginx reverse-proxy in the container network so that I can go to, say...

```
http://localhost/<service-name>/api-docs
```

and it will redirect, inside the container network, to...

```
http://<service-name>:5000/<service-name>/api-docs
```

So, here's the Nginx configuration I've come up... basically, match the first part of the request URI, which should be the service name, and proxy to a host called the same and Nginx *should* add the `$request_uri` on automatically.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location ~* ^/(?<target>.+)/ {
        proxy_pass http://$target:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
}
```

Here's what I get for a `/scheduler/healthcheck` endpoint. All good!

```
api-gateway_1               | 172.19.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018:17:50:24 +0000] "GET /scheduler/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

But, when I try to go to `/scheduler/api-docs`, I have problems. We get to the service container and Swashbuckle does a 301 Redirect from `/scheduler/api-docs` to `/scheduler/api-docs/`.

```
api-gateway_1               | 172.19.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018:17:51:18 +0000] "GET /scheduler/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

And, then, things go bad... we "lose" the `/scheduler` part of the route!

```
api-gateway_1               | 172.19.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018:17:51:18 +0000] "GET /scheduler/api-docs/ HTTP/1.1" 502 576 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
api-gateway_1               | 2018/03/27 17:51:18 [error] 5#5: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /scheduler/api-docs/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.5:80/api-docs:5000", host: "localhost:4000"
```

Why does the Swashbuckle redirect send the request back through Nginx, I thought this would all be handled by the local service, and why is Nginx stripping the necessary route prefix from this request?

How do I get this to behave?!

---

I tried to reconstruct the "whole" URI, just to see what happens...

```
-   proxy_pass http://$target:5000;
+   proxy_pass http://$target:5000$request_uri;
```

And that got *even* worse!

```
api-gateway_1               | 172.19.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018:18:03:48 +0000] "GET /scheduler/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
api-gateway_1               | 172.19.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018:18:03:48 +0000] "GET /scheduler/api-docs/ HTTP/1.1" 502 576 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
api-gateway_1               | 2018/03/27 18:03:48 [error] 5#5: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /scheduler/api-docs/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.5:80/api-docs:5000/scheduler/api-docs/", host: "localhost:4000"
```

---

FYI, everything works fine in my browser if I visit the sites directly (after publishing the ports via Docker, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahem... the problem is a "greedy" regex. The regex capture group `.+`, as defined, will consume *everything* up to the *last* forward-slash.

[image]

You should use a "lazy" regex capture group `.+?` to capture just a single URI segment between two forward-slashes, but not *everything* to the *last* forward-slash!

[image]

Comment: Since this had nothing to do with swagger, swagger-ui or swashbuckle maybe you should refactor the question to focus on the actual issue?